# i used json in the following way in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

This is the code

```
$.post("color/color1", {color : e}, function(data) {
    var out=data + "<a class='one'>total</a>";
    console.log(out);
    output.html(out);
}
```

and this is what browser is putting out

```
blue
string '<span >10000</span><br><span >250000</span><br>' (length=47)
total
```

Now my question is why am i getting all of this formatting code in my output and second 
how to stop it and how come browser is not interpreting `<span>10000</span>` which goes back to the original question.
the php code that puts spans in is as follows

```
foreach( $this->data['votes'] as $array) {
    if($array->color === $obj)
        $output .= '<span >'. $array->votes . '</span>' . '<br>';
}
```

this is what **console.log** puts out

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <small>string</small> 
        <font color='#cc0000'>'&lt;span &gt;10000&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;span &gt;250000&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;'
        </font> 
        <i>
            (length=47)
        </i>
</pre>
<a class='one'>total</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. It looks like you are using `var_dump($output)` instead of `echo $output` in your php code.
2. Ensure that the jQuery object `output` is available in the $.post callback. (inside the `function(data){ ... }` )